# How can I recalibrate my Wiimote sword position while fighting?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In Skyward Sword when I'm trying to strike my sword in the desired directions it often seems that the calibration has gone out of whack, so when I'm trying to strike left-to-right I end up just flailing around randomly.

With other weapons you point the Wiimote towards the screen and press the down arrow to recalibrate it, but when you have the sword out pressing down summons my guardian woman who just bangs on about the enemy I'm fighting.

Is there a way to ensure I get my sword back to a neutral position so my strikes can be more accurate? (Or is it just me being a crap sword fighter, and I should just be more careful and less flaily?)

Comment: Couldn't you just sheathe your sword and pull it out again?

Answer (score 5):

You can go to the pause menu and click the down button in the D-pad, and it will center the Wii remote. (If that's what you wanted.)

Comment: That sounds perfect actually. I'll give that a try.

Comment: hey man did it work

Answer (score 2):

You can recalibrate at any time by going to the pause menu and clicking the "Recalibrate Motion Plus" button in the bottom-left.

Comment: I don't think he meant _that_ recalibration, he just wants the game to reset the normal, neutral position of the Wiimote.

Comment: You can either re-center with a pointer item or re-calibrate and re-center with this menu option. There's nothing else as far as I know.